# Como modificar o link do Botão Alert

Tags: php, javascript

Eu queria saber como mudar o link do botão alerta. Por exemplo, quando apertar `OK` ir para uma página. Eu tentei o seguinte código mas não deu certo:

```
echo  "<script>alert('Clique para ir para a pagina inicial!'); <a href="home.php"></a> </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é um caminho padrão, ou melhor, tem erro de pensamento ai. Quando a pessoa clica no botão ok do alert, significa apenas um consentimento, que ela leu a mensagem, nada mais. Para redirecionar para outro lugar, simplesmente coloque um redirecionamento na linha de baixo da mensagem de echo. Pode ser de redirecionamento em javascript mesmo com o echo do PHP.

```
echo "window.location.href = "http://www.devmedia.com.br"";
```

Answer (score 0):

- Com o método `alert()` só temos uma opção, clicar OK e ir para onde `window.location.href` apontar.

  ```
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
   echo 'alert("Clique para ir para a pagina inicial!");'; 
   echo 'window.location.href = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/";';
   echo '</script>';
  ```
- Com o método `confirm()`, temos duas opções, clicando em `OK`
  ir para onde `window.location.href` apontar e clicando em `Cancelar` fechar a caixa de dialogo e permanecer na página.

  ```
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
   echo 'confirm("Clique OK para ir para a pagina inicial!");'; 
   echo 'window.location.href = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/";';
   echo '</script>';
  ```

> Restrinja o uso das caixas de dialogo de alerta em seus projetos de documentos HTML ou site. A modalidade das janelas atrapalha fluxo de navegação de um usuário por suas páginas. Comunique-se com seus usuários por outros meios como por exemplo janela modal.

**Janela modal puro CSS e HTML**

```css
#modal {
        left: 20%;
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        visibility: visible;
        width: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

        #modal:target{
            opacity: 0;
            top: -50%;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #modal .header, #modal .footer {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        }

        #modal .footer {
            border: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        }

        #modal h2 {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #modal .a {
            float: right;
        }
        
        #a,#b {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         padding: 15px;
        
        }

        #modal .copy, #modal .header, #modal .footer {
            padding: 15px;
        }

    .modal-content {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #modal .copy {
        background: #fff;
    }

    #modal .overlay {
        background-color: #000;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

```html
<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Notification</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <h2>Ir para a pagina inicial?</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="cf footer">
           <a id="a" href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/" class="btn">Sim</a>
            <a id="b" href="#modal" class="btn">Não</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```